# How to set dynamic limits in Logstash throttle plugin based on the value of a field?

Tags: elasticsearch, plugins, logstash, elk, rate-limiting

I am using Logstash throttle plugin to limit the rate of events. Everything is ok if I set `after_count` manually. However I am trying to get this value from Redis. Then set it as a new field and then use it in throttle plugin. So my config file is something like this:

```
filter {
        ruby {
                init => 'require "redis"; $redis = Redis.new(host: "127.0.0.1", port: 6379, db: 5)'
                code => 'event.set("limit", $redis.get("limit"))'
        }

        mutate {
                convert => {
                        "limit" => "integer"
                }
        }

        throttle {
                after_count => %{limit}
                period => 1
                max_age => 2
                key => "[message]"
                add_tag => "throttled"
        }

        if "throttled" in [tags] {
                drop { }
        }
}
```

Although there is no error when checking logs, indexing events is stopped when running this config. Can anyone helps me? Is there anyway to limit the rate based on a value in redis?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot use a sprintf reference in the before_count or after_count options of a throttle filter. The [code](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-throttle/blob/1ff42de61a857e11dbf57d78629e95dc5f19c018/lib/logstash/filters/throttle.rb#L263) uses the option values directly, it does not sprintf them.

"%{limit}" will be converted to zero, so the 'count > 0' always evaluates true, and every event is tagged and dropped.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple logstash java filter to do this.

https://github.com/valsong/logstash-java-rate-limiter

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).